# Jackson - Deserialize array and filter invalid data

Tags: java, android, list, generics, jackson

On an Android project, we are using Retrofit with Jackson to fetch data from a json REST API.

For some technical reasons, the API can return arrays with a mix of valid data and invalid data.

The android app need to fetch these data and filter only valid data.

To do this, we have the idea to add a custom JsonDeserializer for List classes to our ObjectMapper used by Retrofit to Deserialize Json:

```
    SimpleModule listModule = new SimpleModule();
    listModule.addDeserializer(List.class, new ResilientListJsonDeserializer(null));
    objectMapper.registerModule(listModule);
```

But we do not find a solution to implement a JsonDeserilizer that allows us to filter json arrays and retrieve a List with only filtered valid data.

We are blocked on the way by the fact that we don't know how to build array item's. Here our current JsonDeserializer:

```
public class MyJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List> {

    @Override
    public List deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();

        final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(p);

        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = node.elements();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode childNode = iterator.next();

            try {
                Object obj = mapper.convertValue(childNode, ????); // How to get class type of the current parsed objet ?
                result.add(obj);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "impossible to parse json", e);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Maybe you have the solution or an other way to solve the problem on filtering values from deserialized array with Jackson :)

Thanks in advance for your feedback.